# Even after dropping the unique constraint, I am getting ORA-00001: unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID NUMBER(2) UNIQUE ,VAL VARCHAR2(100)
);

Table TEST created.

insert into   test values (1,2);
1 row inserted.
```

I tried to insert the below data again.

```
insert into   test values (1,2);
ORA-00001: unique constraint
```

So I altered the table and removed the unique constraint and tried

```
alter table test modify (id number(2))
Table TEST altered

insert into   test values (1,2);
ORA-00001: unique constraint
```

Comment: You need to drop the constraint using `alter table drop constraint`.

Comment: Your `ALTER TABLE` statement did not drop the constraint. It just changed the data type from `NUMBER(2)` to `NUMBER(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint is stored separately from the column definition -- even when defined using the shorthand you are using.

[This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=909384808feb38975b3358d84fc19892) db<>fiddle illustrates what is happening.

Use `alter table drop constraint`.

Giving constraints names is quite helpful.  Otherwise, you have to search through system tables to find their name so they can be dropped.